# Cannot Change Values of Dictionary in For Loop?

Tags: for-loop, dictionary, f#

So I'm a bit new to F#, but I have a background of C#. I'm writing a code that will iterate over a `Dictionary<string, int>`, add 1 to each element, and add an element to a list if that value exceeds 100. Here is my code:

```
//Early on in the code
let variables = new Dictionary<string, int>()
let variablecnt = new Dictionary<string, int>()
let trash = new List<int>()

//Later on in the code at a higher encapsulation level
    for KeyValue(j, k) in variablecnt do
        variablecnt.[j] <- k+1
        if variablecnt.[j]=100 then
            trash.Add(0)
            variables.Remove(j) |> ignore
```

When this runs, I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

The line number it gives corresponds to:

```
variablecnt.[j] <- k+1
```

I understand what it's saying, but how can I do what I'm attempting to do? I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and researching for an answer, but I'm just not finding anything useful (F# does not have as many resources as a language like C#). I've tried adding the `mutable` keyword to the `let` statements, but that changes nothing.

Also, I use the System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<> dictionary instead of the F# dict() because I guess I'm more familiar with .NET classes. Same reason I'll often use Console.WriteLine instead of printf (sorry!)

Comment: This has nothing to do with F#. You cannot mutate a collection while iterating over it, in any .NET language.

Comment: Ah...I'm not sure how I never came across an error like this in C#. I don't use Dictionaries too often (I use arrays and lists much more often).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try something like this.

I am intentionally going to eschew the standard .NET containers and mutable adding/removing and instead give you an F# style solution to demonstrate the syntax (I think it's best when you're new to avoid falling back on the familiar).

```
// initial variable count
let variablecnt = dict <| Seq.empty<string*int>

/// Convert from KeyValuePair to tuple of (k*v)
let keyVal =
    function
    |KeyValue(k, v) -> (k, v+1)

// split dictionary into twp lists containing values which are
// less than or greater than or equal to 100 respectively
let splitAt100 = 
    Seq.map (keyVal) // map to KeyValuePairs
    >> Seq.toList // convert to list
    >> List.partition (fun (k,v) -> v < 100) // split into tuples based on v < 100

// apply the splitat100 function to the variable count
let lThan100, grEq100 = splitAt100 variablecnt 
// variables is a dictionary of the key value pairs, where the values are less than 100
let variables = lThan100 |> dict
// trash is a list of 0s equal in length to the number of key value pairs with 100+ values
let trash = grEq100 |> List.map (fun _ -> 0)
```

If you want a mutable `variables` field then you can always update the original with this new one once it has been generated.